# Extracting Frames From a Movie file using python

Tags: python, image, ffmpeg, extract

I've been trying to extract frames from a video file, and I've been using the following code as a test before I try to work with my own file.  I get an error having to do with an invalid literal:

```
 import os, sys
 from PIL import Image
 a, b, c = os.popen3("ffmpeg -i test.avi")`
 out = c.read()

 dp = out.index(" ")
 duration = out[dp+10:dp+out[dp:].index(",")]
 hh, mm, ss = map(float, duration.split(":"))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in -toplevel-
    hh, mm, ss = map(float, duration.split(":"))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): cognized as an internal or external command
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Look at the value of `duration`, because it isn't what you're expecting it to be. *Read* your error message.

Comment: Who needs python when you have bash? Isn't python just a wrapper for `bash` anyway?